# Dictionary/list/tuple comprehension from 3 lists

Tags: python

Say I have the following 3 lists:

```py
x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
y = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
z = ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p']
```

I am trying to get the output to:

`[('a',['y1', 'y2'], ['p', 'p']),('b',['y3', 'y4'], ['p', 'p'])]`

x repeats at a fixed known length (here known length is 2, i.e. next in the sequence would be c,c). x % known length is not necessarily 0.
z won't always have the same items.

I have tried with `defaultdict` and many versions of comprehension but can't seem to crack it. The lists I will be working on are actually much larger, therefore for loops take a really long time. So I need something with high performance.

Comment: How the packing works here? Could explain it a bit? Are you factoring same consecutive items in `x` ? is `z` always have same items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `groupby` with `zip`:

```py
from itertools import groupby


x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
y = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
z = ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p']

result = [(k, *list(zip(*grp))[1:]) for k, grp in groupby(zip(x, y, z), lambda s: s[0])]

# which gives
[('a', ('y1', 'y2'), ('p', 'p')), ('b', ('y3', 'y4'), ('p', 'p'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension seems to do the trick:

```
data = [(x[i], [y[i], y[i + 1]], [z[i], z[i + 1]]) for i in range(0, len(x), 2)]
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
[('a', ['y1', 'y2'], ['p', 'p']), ('b', ['y3', 'y4'], ['p', 'p'])]
```

**Note**: I assumed `x` to always have the same values ​​pairwise.